# Solving $\frac{df}{dx} = 2x$ using the definition of a derivative.

Tags: limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

Although it's pretty straightforward to solve the above equation but I was wondering, how about if we use the limit definition of a derivative and then try to solve it. So, the equation looks like $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = 2x$$
Now how should I go about solving it? IMO guessing might be one of the ways but I am not aware of any of the "formal" ones. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: The anti derivative of a polynomial must be a polynomial, finding the polynomial(s) is then easy.

Comment: @VivaanDaga So you mean that I assume $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^∞ {a_n}{x^n}$? And if so, then would considering $f(x)$ as a power or a Fourier series for any other complicated _integrands_ work too?

Comment: You don’t assume anything, you know that the derivative of a finite polynomial is a finite polynomial, so you know it must be in the form of a finite polynomial.

Comment: @VivaanDaga Isn't using anti-derivatives just the usual way?

Comment: @VivaanDaga that’s not enough (assuming the goal is to find *all* functions). How can you be sure a-priori that there aren’t non-polynomials whose derivatives are polynomials? One needs a “heavy-hitting” theorem here, either the fundamental theorem of calculus (not my preferred choice here) or the mean-value theorem for derivatives.

Comment: Yes of course @peek-a-boo. You need to prove uniqueness up to a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $\frac{d}{dx}x^2=2x$; this can be established from the definition of derivative.

Now we have that $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)-x^2]=0$, since the linearity of differentiation can be established from the definition of derivative.

Finally we need to prove from the definition of derivative, and the other properties of real numbers this version of the Mean Value Theorem:

*Suppose that $g(x)$ is differentiable, and that $g'(x)=0$ for all $x$. Then for any $a,b$ we have $g(a)=g(b)$.*

We then have that $f(x)-x^2=k$ for some constant $k$.

I do not believe that there is any proof that does not use the key theorem of the differentiable calculus, namely the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Hmm.. the use of Mean Value Theorem is actuallly clever tbh. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ because of $f'=2x^1$  so
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \\\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a(x+h)^2+b(x+h)+c-(ax^2+bx+c)}{h} =\\ 
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2axh+ah^2+bh}{h} =\\\lim_{h\to 0}2ax+b+ah =2x\\a=1\\b=0\\c \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: As @peek-a-boo explains in his comment on the question this is not a proof: it only shows that the only quadratic solution is $x^2+c$.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a fun exercise $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = 2x$$

let’s assume $f(x)$ is a polynomial

so $f(x) = ax^n$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a(x+h)^n-ax^n}{h} = 2x$$

we can write it like thing where all higher terms of h is removed because they will go to zero

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(ax^n + ax^{n-1}h+…)-ax^n}{h} = 2x$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{anx^{n-1}h+…}{h} = 2x$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0} anx^{n-1} + … = 2x$$

$$ anx^{n-1} = 2x $$

now we can solve for $f(x)$,
$n-1 = 1$,
$a = 1$,
$f(x) = x^2$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How could you just assme the sloution is a monomial? How are you sure there are no other solutions (up to an arbitrary constant)? How are you sure there are no trigonometric, exponential, high degree polynomial, or even non-elementary solutions?

Comment: @Divide1918 You are right why did I assume it’s a polynomial? I do this when I see a differencental equation, assume its a polynomial, then assume it’s exponential, the assume it’s trigonometric, until I can’t see a pattern and I get stuck. We could try for exponential, but it fails so does trigonometric functions.

Comment: But a monomial is far from a general polynomial. What justifies your assumption that it must be a monomial?

Comment: Yeah but by doing this aren't you just using FTC, which is the same as the standard/usual way to solve the DE? (Tbh I don't believe there is a true way with limit definition fo derivatives, or at least it's the same as the usual way, due to the ubiquity of FTC)

Comment: @TedShifrin You are right it is just a simple monomial, I just tried something that might work, I’m not necessarily is the only answer, I just deal with a function I know how to deal with in particular with f(x+h) and see if there is a solution to it, I don’t have a justification, I assumed the answer to be a monomial, if that failed I would try a polynomial, if that failed I would have tried other types of functions.

Comment: But this is not the only solution, right?

Comment: @Divide1918 I’m not sure, I know the fundamental Theorem of calculus is the integral between a and b of f’(x) is f(b) - f(a), I’m not very fluent on how to solve DEs, I just got into calculus this year in high school. but I think you are right this is the method I think people do to solve df/fx = x^n in general.

Comment: @TedShifrin you are right in fact the more general solution would be a polynomial like this x^2 + c, I just didn’t check for more cases because I found one and called it good, and also I would right a + c because if I add a constant number it doesn’t change the df/dx. I just found a possible anti derivative.